# Setting up a selective redirect

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, templates, redirect

I am working on a templating engine in which there is a layout page and content pages (.cntnt). The layout page looks like this:

```
<div id="body">
    <?php
        include_once(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],1) . ".cntnt"); 
    ?>
</div>
```

The idea is really simple: the user makes a request e.g. mysite.com/pageone and are redirected to the layout page silently, here the layout page adds any templating HTML and inserts the requested page (pageone) at the line above. The problem I am having is setting up the redirect.

I am using the following code in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteBase /
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/Layout.php$ 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  (\.html|\.php|/)$
    RewriteRule $ /Layout.php [L] 
</IfModule>
ErrorDocument 404 /404.cntnt
```

This is meant to redirect requests for php, html and extensionless files to the Layout page but return the original file otherwise. It doesn't. Requests for `.html` or `.php` files return a 404 response. E.g. you enter www.mysite.com/pageone in the url bar and press enter, you will get a 404 but if you go to the layout page or the cntnt pages they will load. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried combining the second RewriteCond into the rule itself? `RewriteRule (\.html|\.php|/)$ /Layout.php [L]` The way you  have it looks odd to me.

Comment: @IMSoP Yes, I had it that way for readability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Requests for .html or `.php` files return a 404 response. E.g. you enter `www.mysite.com/pageone` in the url bar

If you're entering `www.mysite.com/pageone` as URL then it won't match this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  (\.html|\.php|/)$
```

And it will indeed by a 404.

You can use this rule:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.cntnt
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule !^(Layout\.php|.+?\.(?:jpe?g|gif|ico|png|tiff|css|js)$ Layout.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: That is the problem, I need it to redirect /page one, /pageone.php and /pageone.html to layout.php but not images and any other types of content..